# Laravel Validate numeric multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, validation, error-handling

I want to give an error message if a string is entered in a integer inputfield with an multidimensional array.

View:

```
<div class="col-md-8">
     <input name="answer[sleep][score]" type="text" class="form-control @error('answer[sleep][score]') @enderror" placeholder="Score" value="{{ @$answer_array['sleep']['score'] }}">
     @error('answer[sleep][score]')
     <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
         <strong>Geen letters alsjeblieft.</strong>
     </span>
     @enderror
     </div>
```

Controller:

```
        $request->validate([
            'answer.sleep.score' => 'nullable|numeric',
        ]);
```

when i click save it just refreshes the page and does nothing. Can anybody please help me, how do i show the error on a multidimensional array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`@error` is a blade directive used to display error messages in your template. The right way to use it is:

```
@error('answer.sleep.score')
  <div>{{ $message }}</div>
@enderror
```

Notice that in order to detect whether the error message exists, I'm using the same format as you did in the validation i.e. `answer.sleep.score` and **NOT** `answer[sleep][score]`.

If you want to add a class to your input element when an error is detected you can do this:

```
<input name="answer[sleep][score]" type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('answer.sleep.score') ? 'error-class' : '' }}" placeholder="Score" value="{{ old('answer.sleep.score') }}">
```

By using `old`, you can pre-fill input field with the posted value.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the dot's, but it didn't work. Apperently i put the wrong $error in my class. It seemed to work on every other page the way i did it, but not with this type array. I modified it a little bit to my linking, but this is definitively the solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression for the validation will be much better then this:

```
$request->validate([
   'answer.sleep.score' => 'nullable|regex:/^[0-9]*$/',
]);
```

This allow you to enter only numbers in the field.

Comment: Sorry, i tried this, but this doesn't work. I get the same result. Page just refreshes. :(

Comment: How's that much better? According to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-numeric), if you specify `numeric` as a rule, the field under validation must be numeric.

Comment: Are you facing issue with how to display error message for the validation in blade file?